# upload with bandwidth throttling in c#

Tags: c#

am trying to move files from local machines to a remote server. Trying to see if there is a better way then BITS to upload files with bandwidth throttling in c#

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this article?

Use a codeproject class called ThrottledStream.

[Bandwidth throttling in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371032/bandwidth-throttling-in-c)