# asp.net create request as mobile device

Tags: c#, mobile, request, dotnet-httpclient, agent

I want to send a link request to any site in asp.net. In doing so, I want the outgoing connection to be perceived as a mobile device. If I want to improve it further, I want the sent link to be at the mobile connection level. For example, 3G or 4G. I'm waiting for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Why you want to do so?

Comment: To measure the response of sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device is determined by the UserAgent header.

To set the user agent header, see [How do I set a default User Agent on an HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076962/how-do-i-set-a-default-user-agent-on-an-httpclient)

Regarding network speed throttling, it is possible, see [Bandwidth throttling in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371032/bandwidth-throttling-in-c-sharp)

Here are some user agents, from https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings

```
Safari for iOS
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1
Android Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
Chrome Mobile
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
Opera Mobile (Blink rendering engine)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-A310F Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/42.7.2246.114996
Opera Mobile (Presto rendering engine)
Opera/9.80 (Android 4.1.2; Linux; Opera Mobi/ADR-1305251841) Presto/2.11.355 Version/12.10
Opera Mini
Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/5.1.21214/28.2725; U; ru) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10
Opera Mini (iOS WebKit)
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) OPiOS/10.2.0.93022 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53
Firefox for Android
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:54.0) Gecko/54.0 Firefox/54.0
Firefox for iOS
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/7.5b3349 Mobile/14F89 Safari/603.2.4
UC Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; en-US; SM-G935F Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.3.8.976 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
Dolphin
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920V Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36
Puffin for Android
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-N750K Build/LMY47X; ko-kr) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Puffin/6.0.8.15804AP
Puffin for iOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-N750K Build/LMY47X; ko-kr) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Puffin/6.0.8.15804AP
Samsung Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SAMSUNG SM-G955U Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/5.4 Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
Yandex Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Lenovo K50a40 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.137 YaBrowser/17.4.1.352.00 Mobile Safari/537.36
MIUI Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; en-us; MI 5 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.146 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/9.0.3
IE Mobile
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; Microsoft; Lumia 950)
Edge Mobile
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; Microsoft; Lumia 950) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.14977
BlackBerry Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Kbd) AppleWebKit/537.35+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.3.3.2205 Mobile Safari/537.35+
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try and write the result here.